# Powershell script to add XML sub-elements

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm getting crazy. I need to modify this XML file in powershell

```
<Smart>
  <Settings>
    <Section name="x">
      <Parameter name="a" value="true" />
      <Parameter name="b" value="0" />
      <Parameter name="c" value="13873" />
      <Parameter name="d" value="true" />
      <Parameter name="e" value="EAI" />
    </Section>
    <Section name="z">
      <Parameter name="h" value="true" />
      <Parameter name="i" value="0" />
      <Parameter name="j" value="13873" />
      <Parameter name="k" value="true" />
      <Parameter name="l" value="EAI" />
    </Section>
  </Settings>
</Smart>
```

What I want to do is add another line such as:

**< Parameter name="f" value="OK" />**

But I want to add the new line inside the first Section < Section name="x">

```
    #Modify XML file
    Write-Host "OPENING XML FILE";
    $path = "\\$computer\$FileName"
    [xml] $xml = Get-Content $path
    
    #return $xml.SmartUpdate.Settings.Section.Parameter

    #set values for the XML nodes you need. This uses the XPath of the value needed.

   **WANT TO ADD THE NEW PARAMETER HERE**

    #Save the file
    $xml.save($path)
    Write-Host "XML FILE SAVED";
```

I cannot find the solution. Please help me

Comment: You can use msxsl and XSLT stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple `Section` nodes, you need to specify the node to append the new childnode to:

```or-tag-here
$path = "\\$computer\$FileName"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw

# create a new childnode and append attributes to it
$childNode = $xml.CreateElement("Parameter")
$attrib = $xml.CreateAttribute('name')
$attrib.Value = 'f'
[void]$childNode.Attributes.Append($attrib)
$attrib = $xml.CreateAttribute('value')
$attrib.Value = 'OK'
[void]$childNode.Attributes.Append($attrib)

# select the parent node to append this childnode to
$parentNode = $xml.Smart.Settings.Section | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'x' }
[void]$parentNode.AppendChild($childNode)

$xml.Save($path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.
Note that my XML skills with Powershell are far from good so I hope someone else has a better solution

```
# Create a new node
$NewNode = $Xml.CreateNode([System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element,"Parameter",$null)
# create the attributes and set the values
$NameAttribute = $XMl.CreateAttribute('name')
$NameAttribute.Value = 'f'
$ValueAttribute = $Xml.CreateAttribute('value')
$ValueAttribute.Value = 'OK'
# append the attributes
$NewNode.Attributes.Append($NameAttribute)
$NewNode.Attributes.Append($ValueAttribute)
# append the new node to the correct parent
$Xml.Smart.Settings.Section.AppendChild($NewNode)
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you. It worked.
What should I do if I had two Sections inside the Settings?